# How to load all images in gridView?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have app with gridView (code below). I download links to images and add to postList. The problem is that the images download when they are displayed. I see only 4 image on screen and when i scroll down then do the next ones are loading. How to change this and load all from links? So that I don't have white boxes when scrolling down.

```
child: GridView.count(
                controller: _controller,
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                crossAxisCount: 2,
                crossAxisSpacing: 12.0,
                mainAxisSpacing: 12.0,
                childAspectRatio: cardWidth/cardHeight,
                children: List.generate(postList.length, (index) {
                  return GestureDetector(
                    onTap: (){
                    },
                    child:
                       new ClipRRect(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
                        child: Image.network(postList.elementAt(index).imageUrl,
                            fit: BoxFit.fitHeight),
                      ),
                    //),
                  );
                }),
              )
```

Comment: You could try to use the [`precacheImage`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/precacheImage.html) function to load some images in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is lazy loading, it is not a good approach to download all images at once, suppose you have 1000 images, and the user just see the 10 images and quits the app, you'll waste the resources of the device by downloading  all images, which is not required at all

Comment: I'm loading 26 images and when user scroll down and hit bottom then get next 26.

Comment: It wouldn't make sense to load all 1000 images, but it might make sense to load, say, 30 (10 for the current screenful, 10 for the previous screenful, 10 for the next) to reduce image loading time when scrolling.